# How can I invert the X and Y axis for the camera controls on Shadow of Mordor?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I find it very very weird and hard for me to not be able to change the X and Y axis settings. I'm used to inverting both, but I don't think there are any settings in-game for this.